# How to unblock my own admin account after 5 failed login attempts?

Tags: users

I entered the wrong admin password more than 5 times, so Drupal has blocked my entry.

I've change the user password directly in MySQL and then tried to login, but is still doesn't work. Also, if I click the request new password link, I don't get an e-mail.

How can I unblock my account?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To answer the question in your title (which appears to become more complicated following your actual question), you just need to clear the `flood` table in your database.  If you're running Drush, then the following should sort you out:

> drush php-eval 'db_query("DELETE FROM `flood`");'

Failing that, just clear the `flood` table from your database manually :)

Comment: That's awfully speedy for a friday afternoon Chappers, I'm starting to think you might not have been in the pub for most of the afternoon. Tsk, tsk.

Comment: @Clive In the pub? On a Friday afternoon?  That'd be nice :-)

Comment: I thought friday drinking was mandatory now? Let me speak to my union rep...

Comment: @Clive I think to have a union, there has to be more than one person in your company doing what you do ;-)

Comment: Rats. To the propaganda room...

Comment: I wouldn't recommend to blindly delete all records of the `flood` table, this would reset all flood control for you website.

Comment: Another way to used. Url: - https://www.drupal.org/project/flood_unblock

Answer (score 8):

Clearing the flood table will give the OP another 5 tries guessing the password. (And if he has messed with the password field directly in MySQL, the passord field may have become munged and therefore useless.)

Clearing the flood table will not allow him to login as admin, which is what I assume the OP actually want to do.

However, there are a couple of other drush commands that may be handy.  The first will produce a one time password reset link for uid 1, the second sets a new password for user `admin`:

```
drush uli
drush upwd admin --password="newpassword"
```

Comment: Good catch! I even edited the question and didn't pick that up ;-)

Answer (score 6):

If you are not much experienced with Drush kind of stuff, you can run the following sql in your phpmyadmin

```
DELETE FROM flood;
```

The same error can be happened if you tried same user name with 5 or more times

Answer (score 6):

Much better solution, which is noticeably absent from other posts about this:

`drush user-unblock {username}`

https://drushcommands.com/drush-7x/user/user-unblock/

EDIT: this still doesn't clear the 'flood' table, unfortunately, which is dumb. As others have mentioned, to actually enable login after `drush user-unblock` in the case of a user being blocked by too many login attempts, you have to get into the database and truncate (dump all data from) the 'flood' table.

As others have mentioned when asking this question, this seems problematic in a production environment.

As usual, someone has already made a module that adds drush commands to clear out the flood table: https://www.drupal.org/project/flood_unblock

Answer (score 2):

Just truncate the table flood

> Truncate flood;